# Monitoring directory using incron

Tags: linux, ubuntu, incron

I am using incron to monitor the file creation event of a directory. It working fine but once for 4 or 5 days its getting freeze.

Once it's freeze, it's not monitoring the file creation event. It started to work back once I manually restarted the incron.service.

what I want is, I want to be notified once incron is freeze. How do get to know incron is freezed state? How do I make a shell script to capture state of incron?